# Running out of memory when partitioning an image with ImagePartition

Tags: image-processing, memory, image3d

I have an `Image3D` object of image type *"Bit16"* with the dimensions 1472 x 1472 x 1472 that I would like to split into small image cubes of dimension 64 x 64 x 64 which would give me a total of 23^3 = 12167 small `Image3D` objects. I want to apply an adaptive thresholding algorithm I already implemented which computes separate thresholds for each image block and then interpolates the computed threshold values ([adaptive thresholding](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/adpthrsh.htm)). For this purpose I use the function `ImagePartition`. The following code illustrates the partitioning:

```
croppped = ImageCrop[image, {1472, 1472, 1472}];
parts = ImagePartition[cropped, {64, 64, 64}];
```

I use `ImageCrop` to add a border to the original image which results in the mentioned  `Image3D` object of dimensions 1472 x 1472 x 1472. If I try to run the partitioning my *Mathematica* kernel crashes with an out of memory error. I have 96 GB RAM installed on my machine. I'm not sure, but the memory should be a sufficient amount of memory available to do the partitioning.

What surprised me is that i can create multiple huge `Image3D` objects and the kernel doesn't crash, but when I partition an `Image3D`, using ImagePartition it does. See the following code for the memory usage when I create another `Image3D` object:

```
MemoryInUse[]
cropped2 = ImageCrop[image, {1472, 1472, 1472}];
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 14461079560
>
> 20840097904

Questions:

1. Is there a simple explanation for this problem?
2. What would be a suitable workaround in order to perform the splitting?

**Edit (08/01/2014)**

First of all thanks very much [UDB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9453/udb) for this nice solution you posted. I now had the time to try out the function `MyImagePartition` on my data and here are the results I obtained so far. First, to get a feeling for the timings and memory usage I created the same test volume and partitioned it on my machine. I then checked whether the original volume can be assembled again to give the volume again.

```
volume = Image3D[RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {8, 9, 10}*64], "Byte"];
First@AbsoluteTiming[ip = ImagePartition[volume, {64, 64, 64}]]
```

> 10.899000

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]    
First@AbsoluteTiming[mip = MyImagePartition[volume, {64, 64, 64}]]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> 248907056
>   1.505000
>   542529936

```
Image3D[ImageAssemble@ip] == volume
```

> True

```
Image3D[ImageAssemble@mip] == volume
```

> True

Then I tested the function `MyImagePartition` on a real image I have. In between the partitioning of the test volume and the real data i quit the kernel to get a fresh Mathematica session. Fortunately, the function is very fast in partitioning my data and memory consumption seems to be no issue. When reassembling it again I checked for the image dimensions of the assembled image.

```
ImageDimensions@testImage
```

> {458, 403, 202}

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]
First@AbsoluteTiming[mip = MyImagePartition[testImage, {64, 64, 64}]]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> 249027112
>   0.278000
>   542635024

```
ImageDimensions@Image3D[ImageAssemble@mip]
```

> {448, 384, 192}

Obviously the dimensions of the reassembled image do not match the original image dimensions. I have to admit that I didn't fully understand the usage of the second parameter 'dwdh'. Is it the option for image padding such that the image matches up with the partitioning block size? I tried several options but failed continuously ;) Besides that issue, would it be possible to add the functionality to create an overlapping partitioning of the image (e.g. give the overlap of the blocks in voxels as an additional parameter). With the built-in function `ImagePartition` this works quite good as follows:

```
parts = ImagePartition[spheroid3d, {64, 64, 64}, {60, 60, 60}, 
   Padding -> 0];
```

Comment: Congratulations, you posted the 10,000th question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### `MyImagePartition`

In the meantime, before *Mathematica 10* will come out, you can enjoy my *on-foot* solution `MyImagePartition`, which both saves memory and time using the `PartitionMap` function from the `Developer` context:

```
MyImagePartition[im_, wh_, dwdh_List: {0, 0, 0}] := 
 Module[{it = ImageType@im,
         cs = First@Options[im, ColorSpace],
         il = First@Options[im, Interleaving],
         is = First@Options[im, ImageSize]},
  If[! (ImageQ@im), Return@$Failed];
  If[Length@ImageDimensions@im == 2,
   Return@Developer`PartitionMap[
     Image[#, it, cs, il, is] &,
     ImageData[im, it],
     If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh}, Reverse@wh],
     If[dwdh == {0, 0, 0}, Reverse@If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh}, wh], Reverse@dwdh]
   ],
   Return@Developer`PartitionMap[
     Image3D[#, it, cs, il, is] &,
     ImageData[im, it],
     If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh, wh}, Reverse@wh],
     If[dwdh == {0, 0, 0}, Reverse@If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh, wh}, wh], Reverse@dwdh]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

I think, the function above, though in part written rather semi-professionally, will work in analogy (sorry, the width and height specification only accepts fixed tile sizes so far) to the built-in `ImagePartion`, both for `Image` and `Image3D` data (for all image data types, such as `"Byte"`, `"Real"`, `"Bit16"` and so on), and also both for `GrayLevel` and `RGBColor` samples (including alpha channels), whereas all other colorspaces like `"LUV"`, `"CMYK"` etc. work as well.

Since my 8GB RAM equipped machine (with `9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)`) does not allow to make tests with `1472^3` volume `"Bit16"` data, instead I take some reduced `"Byte"`-valent test data set (so that no swapping will occur):

```
volume = Image3D[RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {8, 9, 10}*64], "Byte"];
```

Let us see how the built-in function works:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[ip = ImagePartition[volume, {64, 64, 64}]]
```

> `24.633489`

Now let's compare with my work-around:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[mip = MyImagePartition[volume, {64, 64, 64}]]
```

> `3.923255`

```
mip == ip
```

> `True`

I am pretty sure your 96GB will be far enough to let you partition your 3189506048 `"Bit16"`-valent voxels into `64^3` blocks using `MyImagePartition`. Enjoy!

**Addition**

I have just checked the maximum required bytes for both functions using `MaxMemoryUsed[]` (in two separate kernel sessions):

For `ImagePartition` I obtained `6686483552`, while for `MyImagePartition` I got just `1922143136`...

**Extension: `Padding` option added**

As requested by [g3kk0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2024/g3kk0) I have extended the compatibility to the original `ImagePartition` function by adding a `Padding` option. Here is the code:

```
Options[MyImagePartition] = {Padding -> None};
MyImagePartition[im_, wh_, dwdh_List: {0, 0, 0}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{it = ImageType@im, icf, ics = First@Options[im, ColorSpace], 
   iil = First@Options[im, Interleaving], 
   is = First@Options[im, ImageSize], ip = OptionValue[Padding]},
  If[is === (ImageSize -> Automatic), is = ImageSize -> All];
  If[! (ImageQ@im), Return@$Failed];
  If[Length@ImageDimensions@im == 2,
   Return@Developer`PartitionMap[
     Image[#, it, ics, iil, is] &,
     ImageData[If[ip === None,
       im,
       ImageReflect[
        ImageReflect[
         ImageCrop[ImageReflect[ImageReflect[im, Top], Left], 
          MapThread[(Ceiling[#1/#3] - 1)*#3 + #2 &, {ImageDimensions@
             im, If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh}, wh], 
            If[dwdh == {0, 0, 0}, If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh}, wh], 
             dwdh]}], Padding -> ip], Top], Left]
       ],
      it],
     If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh}, Reverse@wh],
     If[dwdh == {0, 0, 0}, Reverse@If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh}, wh], 
      Reverse@dwdh]
     ],
   icf = First@Options[im, ColorFunction];
   Return@Developer`PartitionMap[
     Image3D[#, it, icf, ics, iil, is] &,
     ImageData[If[ip === None,
       im,
       ImageReflect[
        ImageReflect[
         ImageReflect[
          ImageCrop[
           ImageReflect[ImageReflect[ImageReflect[im, Top], Left], 
            Front], 
           MapThread[(Ceiling[#1/#3] - 1)*#3 + #2 &, {ImageDimensions@
              im, If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh, wh}, wh], 
             If[dwdh == {0, 0, 0}, 
              If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh, wh}, wh], dwdh]}], 
           Padding -> ip], Top], Left], Front]
       ],
      it],
     If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh, wh}, Reverse@wh],
     If[dwdh == {0, 0, 0}, 
      Reverse@If[Length[wh] == 0, {wh, wh, wh}, wh], Reverse@dwdh]
     ]
   ]
  ]
```

All known settings for `Padding` can be used. I did some effort to get identical results compared to `ImagePartition`, therefore I added some `ImageReflect` calls (forth and back), since otherwise due to some different rounding inside `ImageCrop` (used for the padding) under certain circumstances `MyImagePartition` vs. `ImagePartition` results would have slightly differed. However, this might be considered as somehow pendatic, and of course is time consuming (remove these `ImageReflect` calls if you want)...

What still is not implemented in `MyImagePartition` is any flexible tile width/height specification.

Enjoy!

Comment: Really nice answer, thanks!

Comment: @g3kk0: Please test your original big partitioning task and let me know what `First@AbsoluteTiming@MyImagePartition` as well as `MaxMemoryUse[]` report.

Comment: I will try to do that. I have to say that I used another workaround instead, so I will have to first look for the code ;)

Comment: I added some information on the application of the function on my data in the question above.

Comment: @g3kk0: Hope the extended version fits your needs. Generally, I think the images should be cropped prior to partitioning in a way so that no padding is required...

Answer (score 14):

This is not a direct answer to your question but it can help you. I see your question is about adaptive thresholding. I propose finding  threshold values without exact partitioning.

```
img = Import["http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/images/son1.gif"]
```

[image]

The simplest is `GaussianFilter` which is analog to $T = mean$ in your link.

```
GF = GaussianFilter[img, 30]
```

[image]

```
Binarize[ImageSubtract[ImageAdd[img, 0.03], GF], 0]
```

[image]

Here 0.03 is the adjustable parameter.

Instead of Gaussian filter you can use

```
MM = ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[MinFilter[img, 20], 0.5],ImageMultiply[MaxFilter[img, 20], 0.5]]
```

which is analog to $T=\dfrac{min+max}{2}$.

There are also `MedianFilter` but unfortunately its time rapidly grows with the sample size

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
 Do[If[# > 1, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ AbsoluteTiming@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

Monitor[ListLogPlot[
  Transpose@
   Table[{timeAvg@GaussianFilter[img, n], timeAvg@MinFilter[img, n], 
     timeAvg@MedianFilter[img, n]}, {n, 10}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {0.01, All}], n]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. I will definitely consider that for my problem and check what results I get.

Comment: +1 I usually use a `Closing` operation instead of a `GaussianFilter`: It's robust, it removes the characters completely and it doesn't smooth the background brightness (as much). It's slower than `GaussianFilter`, but with a rectangular mask, processing time shouldn't depend on filter size, either. (Haven't tested that, though.)

Answer (score 7):

In *Mathematica 9*, `ImagePartition` uses `ImageData` and `Partition` so it is slow and requires a lot of memory.
This issue will be fixed in *Mathematica 10*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do the adaptive thresholding using the built-in `ImageFilter` function. To apply this to the "Sonnet for Lena" as in ybeltukov's answer, define an auxiliary function that does the local thresholding:

```
adaptThresh[x_, threshRat_] := Module[{center, thisPix}, 
   center = (First[Dimensions[x]] + 1)/2;
   thisPix = x[[center, center]];
   Boole[thisPix > threshRat Mean[Flatten[x]]]];
```

`x` is the local portion of the image and the output is 1 whenever `threshRat` times the Mean of the portion is less than the pixel value. To apply this to the image

```
img = Import["http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/images/son1.gif"];
ImageFilter[adaptThresh[#, 0.95] &, img, 2]
```

[image]

Since your file is so large, it would probably make sense to use `ImageFileFilter` which operates directly on the file (rather than reading everything into memory).

Comment: Does the time of this method grows fast with the radius of the filter?

Comment: @ybeltukov -- Yes, because the filter is n by n (where n is the parameter given to the filter). On the other hand, as long as the underlying changes are smooth, it shouldn't be necessary to use a large n (I used n=2 for the above example).

Comment: It was my idea half a year ago, but I reject it because of bad scalability. It will be quite slow for OP's 1472^3 data. Anyway, +1 for implementing this!

Comment: @bills: Thanks for the nice answer. Since my data is quite large, I will try it with the ImageFileFilter idea you proposed and see what comes out. I will add the results to the question.